# Flask App works on localhost but Error 500 on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I created a flask app for video streaming. It runs fine on localhost but gives Internal server error for a particular request.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
"""Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
   return Response(gen(Camera()),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

**index.html**

```
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
```

Everything is working fine except this. It says client error 500 video_feed not found. I don't know where the issue is as this is working fine on localhost.

I  don't know if this help :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

**Error log**

```
2018-06-13T11:50:08.542211+00:00 app[web.1]: Camera warming up ...
2018-06-13T11:50:09.543131+00:00 app[web.1]: OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in throwOnEror, file /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp, line 145
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545191+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-13 11:50:09 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Error handling request /video_feed
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545195+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545200+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545203+00:00 app[web.1]: self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545204+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 181, in handle_request
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545206+00:00 app[web.1]: for item in respiter:
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545208+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 704, in __next__
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545209+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._next()
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545211+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 81, in _iter_encoded
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545212+00:00 app[web.1]: for item in iterable:
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545214+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 18, in gen
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545216+00:00 app[web.1]: frame = camera.get_frame()
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545218+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/morse_camera.py", line 22, in get_frame
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545219+00:00 app[web.1]: ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545221+00:00 app[web.1]: cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp:145: error: (-10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function throwOnEror
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545223+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545462+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.67.237.54 - - [13/Jun/2018:11:50:09 +0000] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "-"
2018-06-13T11:50:09.545728+00:00 app[web.1]: Camera disabled and all output windows closed
```

Comment: Where can I find them. I can just see my deploy logs in Activity feed

Comment: @JonasLochmann I have added the error logs

Comment: @JonasLochmann I may have figured it out. I think when you run webcam from remote server your browser asks for permission but in this case we are requesting it from server side which can happen. Am I right